# how to store functions inside an array and call one single function as array[index]

Tags: python

I want to store multiple functions inside an array and execute one function when i call array[index] to be executed and not all the functions inside the array, how to do it in python?

Example:

```
     array = [  function2(1, 2), function3(2, 3)]
     array[0] #Execute array[0] and not all the functions inside array
```

Comment: To store functions, you'd do `array = [ function2, function3 ]`. To call a function you need `()`: `array[0](1, 2)`.

Comment: @melpomene Is their a way to pass parameters inside the array and not when doing array[0]?

Comment: @aranfey I don't see how that's a duplicate.

Comment: @melpomene The OP wants to store partially (or completely) applied functions a list and call them later, no? Feel free to reopen if you disagree though.

Comment: @Aran-Fey OP wants accessing an array element (`array[0]`) to call a function instead (`function2(1, 2)`). The whole thing looks like an XY problem to me.

Comment: Well, if the OP really can't stand the minor change in syntax (`array[0]()`), then all they need to do is write a `list` subclass that does that automatically. But they can't expect us to write that class for them, so I think the dupe is fine.